# How to draw a surface plot without black edges in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

The black lines are awful, how can I get rid of them? I want only the colored surfaces.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Another choice is to set the *edgeColor* and/or *lineStyle* properties of the surface handle object to *none*.

```
>> hSurf = surf(X,Y,Z,'EdgeColor','none','LineStyle','none','FaceLighting','phong');
```

Answer (score 17):

This is a more general solution, you can change the edgeColor after the surface has been created too.  It does not rely on LineStyle and FaceLighting.

```
a= peaks(1000);
h = surf(a)
set(h, ‘edgecolor’,'none’)
```

Note, I have made a 45 second video that shows this occurring and how to fix it.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/08/13/matlab-basics-setting-edge-color-for-large-surface-plots/

Answer (score 11):

The shading command is your friend:

shading flat - gives you the surface without mesh lines

shading interp - interpolates colours between patches to give a smooth finish

shading faceted - gives you the surface with black mesh lines (similar to flat)

Comment: I executed the shading flat before the surf command, but I saw no difference. Why is that?

Comment: You need to execute it after the surf command, there may be a way of setting the default shading for a new figure, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `shading interp` is the one you're looking for.